# Android SQLite: CursorAdapter gets stuck in constructor, possibly wrong Cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, android-cursoradapter

In my application, there is a database, and it also has a master/detail flow type list interface. The list has a CursorAdapter. When I try to initiate the CursorAdapter with a Cursor, it gets stuck in the constructor.

The implementation is the following:

```
public class PlaceAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public PlaceAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, false);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placerow, null);
    bindView(row, context, cursor);
    return row;
}

// UI elements
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Place from Cursor
    Place place = PlaceDbLoader.getPlaceByCursor(cursor);

    // UI elements...
    ImageView imageViewIcon = ...

}


@Override
public Place getItem(int position) {
    getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

    return PlaceDbLoader.getPlaceByCursor(getCursor());
}

}
```

I am trying to use that Adapter to handle my list items. In the ListFragment, I have an AsyncTask to fetch all data and return the respectable Cursor:

```
//Async task for fetching data
private class GetAllTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    private static final String TAG = "GetAllTask";

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Doinbg0");

            //IMPORTANT
            Cursor result = dbLoader.fetchAll();

            if (!isCancelled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Doinbg1");
                if(result==null)Log.d(TAG, "DoinbgNULL");
                return result;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled, closing cursor");
                if (result != null) {
                    result.close();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "Doinbg2");
                return null;
            }
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Doinbg3");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.d(TAG, "Fetch completed, displaying cursor results!");
        try {
            if (adapter == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec 0");

                if(result==null) Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec NULL");

                //IMPORTANT
                adapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), result);

                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec 1");

                setListAdapter(adapter);

                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec 2");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec 3");
                adapter.changeCursor(result);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec 4");
            }


            getAllTask = null;
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExec done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that it gets stuck on

```
adapter = new PlaceAdapter(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), result);
```

According to the logcat, the Log messages are the following:

```
GetAllTask﹕ Doinbg0
GetAllTask﹕ Doinbg1
GetAllTask﹕ Fetch completed, displaying cursor results!
GetAllTask﹕ onPostExec 0
```

I suspect that something is wrong with the `result` or the database itself.

Here is the `dbLoader.fetchAll();` implementation:

```
public Cursor fetchAll(){
    // cursor for all records (where = null)
    return mDb.query(
            DbConstants.Place.DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[]{
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_TITLE,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_LAT,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_LNG,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_TYPE,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_RADIUS,
                    DbConstants.Place.KEY_ENABLED
            }, null, null, null, null, DbConstants.Place.KEY_TITLE);
}
```

Here is the script for creating the table:

```
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table if not exists "+DATABASE_TABLE+" ("
                    + KEY_ROWID +" integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_DESCRIPTION +" text, "
                    + KEY_LAT + " real not null, "
                    + KEY_LNG +" real not null, "
                    + KEY_TYPE +" text, "
                    + KEY_RADIUS +" real not null, "
                    + KEY_ENABLED +" text"
                    + ");";
```

I would appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction on this one, I am completely clueless as to what is going wrong here.

---

Solution:

I have found the problem: I forgot to include `DbConstants.Place.KEY_TITLE,` in the `fetchAll()` query.

Comment: What is the error that you see?

Comment: It doesnt give an exception, it just gets stuck in the constructor. It also shows an endless 'loading circle' in the fragment view.

Comment: Is the AsyncTask implementation inside a Fragment? Use getActivity() instead of getActivity().getApplicationContext() and then can you update the results?

Comment: Produces exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I did a little digging around and I found the cause - you are calling bindView() from within the newView() method. You should not make this call as bindView() is called automatically by Android to inflate the views and attach the data.

What happens is you are calling this method from which it never returns and hence you just keep seeing the endless loading circle. So now your new method should look like:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.placerow, null);
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Nope, same result. I am pretty sure the problem is within the `result` Cursor.

Comment: I have found the problem: I forgot to include `DbConstants.Place.KEY_TITLE,` in the `fetchAll()` query. Thank you very much for your help though, much appreciated!